# Hirzebruch Surface F2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Can the Hirzebruch Surface $F_2:=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(2))$ be obtained by some GIT quotient of $\mathbb{P}^4$ (or $\mathbb{C}^4$)?

Comment: GIT quotient can mean many things. But at least there are no surjective morphisms from $\mathbb{P}^4$ to $F_2$.

Comment: In Audin's book she explains how to construct a projective toric variety, whose polytope has $n$ facets (4 in your case), as a GIT quotient of $\mathbb C^n$. Essentially it amounts to repeated use of symplectic cutting.

Comment: @Allen Knutson which book is this?

Comment: Michele Audin, The Topology of Torus Actions on Symplectic Manifolds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the interpretation of your question, the answer is *Yes*.

In fact the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_n =\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(n))$ is the quotient of $X = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} \times \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ with respect to the group action
$$ \mathbb{G}_m^2 \times X \to X, \quad (\lambda,\mu) \cdot (s,t;x,y) = (\lambda s, \lambda t; \mu x, \lambda^{-n} \mu y).$$

From a highbrow perspective, such a realisation exists as $\mathbb{F}_n$ is toric. (Every toric variety is a quotient of an open subset of an affine space by the action of some multiplicative group, by the theory of Cox rings).

Comment: As a comment: this is quite useful, as all automorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_n$ are in fact automorphisms of $X$ homogeneous for the action of $\mathbb{G}_m^2$. This allows then two write these globally.

Comment: this is very useful ...but i wanted to realise as a quotient $\mathbb{A}^4$ by $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}^*$...this should be something modified GIT